# RavenDb Select() downcasts instead of selecting the neccessary fields

Tags: ravendb

```
public class PersonBrief
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public PersonBrief(Person person)
    {
        Id = person.Id;
        Picture = person.Picture;
    }
}

public class Person : PersonBrief
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

var results = session.Query<Person>()
   .Select(x => new PersonBrief(x))
   .ToList();

Assert.IsNull(results[0] as Person); // Fails
```

Is this a bug? If not, what would be the correct way to select only the fields i'm interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would *work* if you move the `.ToList` before the `.Select`, but that would be doing the work on the client.

If you want to do it on the server, you need to use `As` in your query, and you need a static index that does a `TransformResults`.  See [these docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/results-transformation/of-type).